# QML Image size is ignored

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a ToolButton in QML with an image with size 48x48 pixels:

```
ToolButton {
    contentItem: Image {
        source: "Icons/idea48.png"
    }
}
```

if I set width and height nothing changes:

```
ToolButton {
    contentItem: Image {
        source: "Icons/idea48.png"
        width: 5
        height: 5
    }
}
```

on the screen it is still 48x48.

And even adding fill Mode does not help:

```
ToolButton {
    visible: scene.serviceMode
    contentItem: Image {
        source: "Icons/idea48.png"
        width: 10
        height: 10
        fillMode: Image.Stretch
        sourceSize: {
            width: 48
            height: 48
        }
    }
}
```

the sourceSize should be 48 to render image with high pixel density.

I also tried to put Image inside Item, but with no success:

```
ToolButton {
    contentItem: Item {
        width: 24
        height: 24
        Image {
            source: "Icons/idea48.png"
            fillMode: Image.Stretch
            sourceSize: {
                width: 48
                height: 48
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The image size is overflowing out of the item. Set the `Image` width and height to the size you want, not the `Item` size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt Quick Controls 2.3 (Qt 5.10) adds built-in support for [button icons](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-abstractbutton.html#button-icons). By default, different styles may request different icon sizes, according to their design guidelines, but you can easily override the icon size.

```
ToolButton {
    icon.width: 24
    icon.height: 24
    icon.source: "Icons/idea48.png"
}
```

What comes to high-DPI support, consider providing @Nx versions like the Gallery example does: http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/examples/quickcontrols2/gallery/icons/gallery?h=5.10

Comment: good answer, but on QT Forum I was told that @Nx does not work on UWP and Android, see https://forum.qt.io/topic/83936/can-i-provide-alternative-images-with-2x-suffix-on-android

Comment: Qt has fully cross-platform high DPI support since Qt 5.6. Qt Quick Controls 2, originally introduced in Qt 5.7, bases its scalability on the automatic high DPI scaling. http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/01/26/high-dpi-support-in-qt-5-6/

Answer (score 1):

### Answer 1

Set the `sourceSize` of the `Image` in order to influence its `implicitWidth` and `implicitHeight`, which are used by the `ToolButton` to determine the size of the `contentItem`.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                contentItem: Image {
                    source: "Icons/idea48.png"
                    sourceSize.width: 10
                    sourceSize.height: 10
                    fillMode: Image.Pad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Answer 2

Put the `Image` inside an `Item` so that the `Image` is not resized by the `ToolButton` and its dimensions remain exactly as specified by `width` and `height`.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                contentItem: Item {
                    Image {
                        source: "Icons/idea48.png"
                        width: 10
                        height: 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Answer 3

Force the size of the `contentItem`.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    header: ToolBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            ToolButton {
                contentItem: Image {
                    source: "Icons/idea48.png"
                }

                Component.onCompleted: {
                    contentItem.width = 10
                    contentItem.height = 10
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is a waste of my time to post something that does not relate to my question

Comment: the sourceSize should be 48 to render image with high pixel density.

Comment: If you don't like sourceSize then another option is to put your `Image` inside an `Item`

Comment: putting Image inside Item does not take an effect, see my edit in the post